# Magento2 loading speed is very slow

Tags: performance, magento2, loading

I have got an issue with Magento project loading speed.
I have built Magento2 project and worked on it and hosted it in CONTABO server.

The server RAM is 16GB. I think it's enough for hosting.
But when I am trying to access it, the loading speed is very slow and I can't find the reason why it is.
The loading time is upto 1min. Terribly slow...

You can check the site through this url: https://31.220.82.149/
(I haven't purchased domain yet, cause I haven't made decision. I wonder if it is the reason but anyway very slow if you check this)

php 7.4, composer 2.5.4, ubuntu 20.04 ...
I tried to clear cache, minify js/css files, set mode to production etc as I can do but the loading time is very slow...

Please check this and help me solve the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards

I tried to clear cache, minify js/css files, set mode to production etc as I can do but the loading time is very slow...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Run the Google page speeds and generate the report and follow that one.
2. Advanced JS bundling will help you more for performance improvement.
3. Check the browser network and try to remove thr failed requests.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with time to first byte (TTFB). From my experience it comes from a poorly coded 3rd-party extension. It happens with Magento.

Here is what I would suggest:

1. Use tideways. It's a code profiler that will tell you what's slowing the site down. It's free for the first couple of weeks.
2. If you can't use tideways - turn off custom plugins one by one and see if it makes a difference.
3. Are you using a custom theme? Try changing to a default Luma theme and see if the site becomes faster.

As always, enable all caching:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

And run in production mode:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

See if it helps.

PS: I wrote a long article on [how to speed up Magento 2](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento-2). It has other tips, check it out if you could.